# MVC asp.net server side timer to prevent user from editing timer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, timer

I have a MVC asp.net quiz application. You have a variable amount of time to take the quiz, and if time runs out, then the answers are automatically submitted.

Currently, I have the timer setup in Javascript, with the amount of time being held in the Controller - `Session["EndTime"]`. But, my understanding is that a user can edit the Javascript and change the timer when it is implemented in Javascript. If true, how do I run the timer in the Controller and send an Action once the timer runs out?

Comment: If you never edit the Session end time then you can always check any answer's server-side timestamp against the end time even if the user manages to adjust the javascript side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server can't *force* the browser to submit anything, that's what the JavaScript code would do.  And, yes, the user can choose to modify that if he or she wants.

What the server would do is keep track of two things:

- A unique identifier for that instance of the "test"
- A date/time stamp of when the "test" began (or, conversely, when it expires, as either value carries the same amount of information)

The first value is included in the form sent to the browser, basically just a hidden form field.  When a test result is posted to the server, the server-side code uses the identifier to look up the persisted date/time stamp to compare it with the current date/time.  If more time than expected has elapsed, reject the test results with an error.

Basically, the server-side code can't force the user to submit the results.  But it *can* reject results which aren't submitted in time.

Comment: So there is no way to have a secure timer that, when expired, submits the form?

Comment: @LoganJahnke: Depends on what you mean by "secure" I guess.  The terms for the "test" are defined by the page you present to the client, and the code therein.  "Security" is a server concern.  If the user tries to be clever and change the code client-side, the only result is that the user fails the test.  So the "security" was achieved.

Comment: Using signalR we can enforce the client to submit the page, We can set the timer on the server and can send the push notification to client when the timer expire. Once push message will be received by the client then we can submit the page on the server.

Comment: @AshishShukla: SignalR isn't magic, the client-side code is still just as subject to user interference as any other client-side code.  The push notification from SignalR would *suggest* to the client that it submit the form.  But if the user has *modified* the client-side code or is spoofing the test in some way, that suggestion would simply be ignored.  Implementing SignalR in this case would add significant complexity to achieve no benefit.